# I am getting an error while updating and would like an explanation

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 22.10

Hi I am getting the following error after I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:712 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'elantech_smbus=0'
```

Additionally, a list of packages that are not getting upgraded is starting to get longer. I also get the following message after upgrading from the terminal.

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  apport apport-gtk libldap-2.5-0 libldap-2.5-0:i386 libldap-common libllvm15
  libllvm15:i386 libnautilus-extension4 nautilus nautilus-data python3-apport
  python3-problem-report
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
```

Let me know if any of you have any ideas what could be going on. The first package was not upgraded a few days ago. Then the number of "not upgraded" has slowly been increasing.

Comment: You've not said how you're applying all upgrades; eg. `apt upgrade` can leave some behind as the documentation mentions (ie. `man apt` and explore; its why `apt full-upgrade` exists as it perform the upgraded and will remove packages as required where upgrade will not). The restrictions on `apt upgrade` allow you to install only what may not impact running apps & may require reboot, allowing you to schedule when you to full-upgrade at a more suitable time.  Are you using a default/supported kernel, in which case which is it?  (your first kernel module detail may require more detail from you)

Comment: I am running lots of machines on 22.04.  This seems more and more common.  Eventually it works itself out.  You can go to sudo apt install packageName if you want.  But waiting a few days will likely work it out.

Comment: I have run `apt full-upgrade` and restarted and I get the same result. I just ran it again just to make sure. Before writing  this used `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

I'm using the 5.19.0-38-generic kernel. I'm running Ubuntu 22.10

Comment: Your packages not installing will relate to *phased updates* then.. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/phased-updates-in-apt-in-21-04/20345 etc  (they became default for non-security at 21.04)

Comment: Yes. I understand now. Thanks for answering this for me!

Answer (score 2):

> ignoring bad line starting with 'elantech_smbus=0'

I believe the line should read:

```
options psmouse elantech_smbus=0
```

Please use a text editor to correct the line.

As to the packages being kept back, these are phased updates.

Phased updates are software updates that are gradually rolled out to users rather than all users getting the updates at the same time. In an update system that doesn't use phased updates, all users are immediately offered an update as soon as it is made available.

In the past, before phased updates were used with Apt, any time an update was pushed out, all Ubuntu users would immediately be able to install the update. And if that update happened to be wonky, it could mess up a lot of people's systems all at once. Phased updates make it so that, in the event an update is bad, it gets caught early before everyone gets the update.

This is a natural and expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that setting and as far as I can tell I has worked. I'll keep an eye on it and make sure that I don't have any issues going forward. Thanks too for the explanation of the uninstalled updates. That will put my mind at ease.